# CSS Gradient Compatibility issue in XDK HTML5 App

Tags: android, ios, css, intel-xdk, html5-apps

I have a CSS code for using gradient in my HTML5 app in XDK. However When I debug my CSS codes with XLint, It says linear-gradient is not compatible with apps in:
Android (2.3,4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3) 
IOS 6.0

```
background:linear-gradient(rgb( 59, 89, 152), rgb(109, 132, 180)) repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);
```

How I can use CSS gradient which can be compatible with all versions of Android and IOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I understand from [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients) you should be able to use linear-gradient on IOS 6 and Android 4.* with one caveat, you need to prepend it with `-webkit-`, i.e.  you'll want your css file to contain two lines for the background, instead of just the one:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb( 59, 89, 152), rgb(109, 132, 180)) repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);
background: linear-gradient(rgb( 59, 89, 152), rgb(109, 132, 180)) repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);
```

Android 2.3 shows 'partial' support, so it might work or it might have issues.  My guess is it has a good likelihood as it's straightforward linear gradient.

Also, at some point in the past, the standard for gradient was in flux and there were some different approaches, but again linear-gradient is pretty stable, so just prepending it with `-webkit-` will hopefully do the trick.

I haven't tried this on android or IOS myself, but from what I read it should work.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Just as you said in Android 2.3 the support is not complete but in other versions, is OK.